# Find duplicate elements across rows by selected columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to get a new data frame with all the recurring elements across a number of selected columns. So, for example, if I have the following df I'd like to run a search for duplicate elements by columns V2, V3, V4.

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1   zz  aa  ee  213
2   aa  ff  xx  254
3   bb  hh  gg  235
4   zz  hh  hh  356
5   yy  cc  dd  796
6   ii  jj  kk  954
```

I would like to get all the rows that contained at least an element that is a duplicate from another of the selected columns or rows. Moreover, the duplicate function in R only select the duplicates, leaving out the 'originals', which I'd also like to include.

So the final df would look like this:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1   zz  aa  ee  213
2   aa  ff  xx  254
3   bb  hh  gg  235
4   zz  hh  hh  356
```

Comment: Can you `dput` your example data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R, we can `unlist` the selected columns (`cols`), get the `duplicated` values and select rows that have those values.

```
cols <- c('V2', 'V3', 'V4')

vals <- unlist(df[cols])
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], `%in%`, vals[duplicated(vals)])), ]

#  V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
#1  1 zz aa ee 213
#2  2 aa ff xx 254
#3  3 bb hh gg 235
#4  4 zz hh hh 356
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:6, V2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("aa", "bb", "ii", "yy", "zz"), class = "factor"), 
V3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("aa", 
"cc", "ff", "hh", "jj"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 
6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("dd", "ee", "gg", "hh", "kk", 
"xx"), class = "factor"), V5 = c(213L, 254L, 235L, 356L, 
796L, 954L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I'm obviously new to R and to programming in general. What if I, then, want to check for duplicates by pairs of rows? So that it check whether the combination of col 1 and 2, or, the combination of row 3 and 4 contains a duplicate. Could I simply do this:
duplicated(df [, 1:2 | 3:4 ])

Comment: Do you want to check for duplicates in rows or columns? Maybe it is better to ask a new question including all the details along with expected output.

Comment: Sure. I will post another question also. I'd like to check for duplicates in rows, selecting different pairs of columns.

Comment: Maybe you can try `df[Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(df[c('V1', 'V2')], \`%in%\`, vals[duplicated(vals)])) |
df[Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(df[c('V3', 'V4')], \`%in%\`, vals[duplicated(vals)])), ], ]`

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your question correctly, the following is one way to go. Your data is called `mydf`. I chose columns that have character. (You may have factors.) Then, I created a character vector and checked which elements have duplication and obtained unique values, which is called `dupes`. Using this, I subsetted `mydf`. If any element in V2, V3, and V4 contains one of the elements in `dupes`, R returned rows.

```
library(dplyr)

unlist(select_if(mydf, is.character)) %>%
.[duplicated(.)] %>% 
unique -> dupes

filter_at(mydf, vars(V2:V4), any_vars(. %in% dupes))

#  V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
#1  1 zz aa ee 213
#2  2 aa ff xx 254
#3  3 bb hh gg 235
#4  4 zz hh hh 356
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(V1 = 1:6, V2 = c("zz", "aa", "bb", "zz", "yy", 
"ii"), V3 = c("aa", "ff", "hh", "hh", "cc", "jj"), V4 = c("ee", 
"xx", "gg", "hh", "dd", "kk"), V5 = c(213L, 254L, 235L, 356L, 
796L, 954L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant [@Ronak-Shah's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59647449/10488504) solution using `colSums` and `apply` instead of `Reduce` and `lapply`.

```
cols <- c('V2', 'V3', 'V4')
vals <- unlist(df[cols])
vals <- unique(vals[duplicated(vals)])
df[colSums(apply(df[cols], 1, "%in%", vals)) > 0,]
#  V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
#1  1 zz aa ee 213
#2  2 aa ff xx 254
#3  3 bb hh gg 235
#4  4 zz hh hh 356
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- subset(df,apply(df[2:4], 1, function(x) any(x %in% unique((z<-unlist(df[2:4]))[duplicated(z)]))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  V1 V2 V3 V4  V5
1  1 zz aa ee 213
2  2 aa ff xx 254
3  3 bb hh gg 235
4  4 zz hh hh 356
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:6, V2 = c("zz", "aa", "bb", "zz", "yy", 
"ii"), V3 = c("aa", "ff", "hh", "hh", "cc", "jj"), V4 = c("ee", 
"xx", "gg", "hh", "dd", "kk"), V5 = c(213L, 254L, 235L, 356L, 
796L, 954L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```